# Should I chooses fuse with a lower value than nominal?

Tags: fuses

I have found this sheet about fuses and it makes zero sense to me - a fuse rated 30A will only blow at 50A?

Does that mean I have to choose a lower value, like ~20A for my <30A application?

[image: this]

Comment: You choose a fuse based on what you are trying to protect.

Answer (score 5):

Fuses are rated according to their normal current, not the trip current.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuse_(electrical))

> **Rated current I<sub>N</sub>**
> A maximum current that the fuse can continuously conduct without interrupting the circuit.
> ...
> **Time vs current characteristics**
> The operating time is not a fixed interval but decreases as the current increases. Fuses are designed to have particular characteristics of operating time compared to current. A standard fuse may require twice its rated current to open in one second, a fast-blow fuse may require twice its rated current to blow in 0.1 seconds, and a slow-blow fuse may require twice its rated current for tens of seconds to blow.

The curves you show explain that yes, the fuse doesn't blow until it has had a certain amount of current for a certain amount of time.  And specifically, a 30 A fuse should never blow at 30 A.

This stops the fuse blowing every time an inrush current briefly exceeds the normal operating current.

Answer (score 5):

Fuses are rated at the current that they *will not* blow. They will often also have curves that indicate the conditions at which they are guaranteed to blow. In between, there is no guarantee. e.g. A 30 A fuse may blow at 35 A after a long time.

So, due to part tolerance, your plan to use a smaller value fuse will not work.

Comment: that is what i thought. the temperature, pressure will affect the fuse parameters.